# How to install a ssl certificate from uwp app code

Tags: c#, windows, security, ssl, uwp

I need to install a self-signed SSL certificate to trusted root on the windows device from my uwp app code how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API in UWP.

If you want to use PowerShell commands in UWP, you need to use desktop bridge to use commands. It is recommended to refer to Stefan Wick’s blog here https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/